# Running exe in VSCode produces no output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to compile C++ in VSCode. I followed the walkthrough [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

When I run the example program in VSCode terminal, nothing is output into the terminal. I tried in powershell and in cmd using the dropdown in VSCode terminal window.

When I run the .exe from a standalone `cmd` terminal, it works fine. Could the problem be something about not knowing how to write the output? I'm guessing the program runs but just doesn't know where to output.

Comment: I can think of literally nothing that would affect the VS Code terminal in this way. Did you create a build task? How are you compiling the code? What shell does VS Code claim to be using? I bet you just didn't click back over to the terminal after executing a task.

Comment: @sweenish .. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I opened VS code before adding mingw to my PATH. I simply had to restart VS code. I really figured each time I opened a new terminal in VS Code, it would.. open a new terminal. Perhaps they do some kind of virtual terminal and it's really all one terminal from launch? Who knows. Either way, restart VS code.

Answer (score 1):

Command Prompt method :

first changer the directory to where file is located.

```
g++ -o program Menu-driven-program-DAA.cpp&program.exe
```

Running Cpp program through powershell terminal in vscode:

```
g++ -o program Menu-driven-program-DAA.cpp
.\program.exe
```

I've mentioned both the commands in vscode powershell terminal seperately because it throws an error

**Note**:- try gcc instead of g++ if it doesn't works for me only g++ did.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and by pure chance following worked in my case: When I opened VSC from a GIT shell via 'code .', I didn't get any output from a shell within VSC. But when I opened VSC from windows command prompt via 'code .' and executed the same file again and it worked.